# Get first entry from loop / while

Tags: php

I need the first ID from a loop.

**Loop:**

```
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{

echo ($row['post_id']) . '<br /><br />';

}
```

**Echo Result:**

```
817856<br /><br />817865<br /><br />817870<br /><br />817871<br /><br />817873<br /><br />817874<br /><br />
```

In this case I need only the Number **817856**

**var_dump**

```
var_dump($row['post_id']);
```

**var_dump Result:**

```
string(6) "817856" string(6) "817865" string(6) "817870" string(6) "817871" string(6) "817873" string(6) "817874"
```

**I tried:**

reset and array_shift without success. Thank you

Comment: use a variable to track your rows and get the first ID from here.

Comment: Just don't do it in a while loop... just do `$row = $sql_fetchrow($result);`

Comment: but I need the while, the while is way longer, I have only shorten it.

Comment: Instead of while using if condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a variable to track the loop and get the first ID while looping. By default you have to assign a variable as true and get the ID inside the loop also make that variable false so that the variable always stay false. Using the IF condition it will be OK.

```
$flag = true;
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result)){
    if($flag === true){
        $ID = $row['post_id'];
        $flag = false;
    }
    echo ($row['post_id']) . '<br /><br />';
}

echo $ID; // 817856
```

If you need just the first ID then it will be shorter version. Cause the query only returns the first row when we don't use the loop.

```
$row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
echo $row['post_id']; //817856
```

Comment: thank you. The first solution works. Great. The second should work also but it shows a different number. First give 817856 - Second Solution give: 817865 - do you have a Idea why?

Comment: yes I did but then I need two querys instead of 1. The first solution works perfect, thank you. I take this one :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$i = 0;
$result;

while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{

  if ($i > 0) 
    {
        break;    
    }

  echo ($row['post_id']) . '<br /><br />';

  $result = $row['post_id'];

  i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you too for your work. Works also very nice :)